# How to get the number of pages count on radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

How can I get the number of pages in a `RadGrid` through code? I tried the following but it always returned 1, although there are 10 pages.

```
mygridView.PageCount.ToString();
```

I also tried the following

```
mygridView.MasterTableView.PageCount.ToString();
```

I got the same result. The Rad Grid has `AllowPaging= "true"`

Basically all I want is to display in a label,  "There are currently 300 records in 2 of 10 pages."

I need to get the "10" from the total pages in the `RadGrid`.

Thank you

Comment: I think that you need to make a separate call to see how many records you have.

Comment: How is your `GridView` bound? Also I assume you've set the `PageSize` property to something smaller than the total number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)   {
   string str = RadGrid1.PageCount.ToString();   }
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the grid how many records there are in total. This is done by setting the grid's VirtualItemCount property (you will have to query the total number of records).

For details, have a look at the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/telerik.web.ui-telerik.web.ui.radgrid-virtualitemcount.html) page or refer to the [online demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/custompaging/defaultcs.aspx) for custom paging.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Protected Sub grid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles grid.ItemDataBound
        If TypeOf e.Item Is GridPagerItem Then
            ' -- Dim summaryCount as integer
            summaryCount += CType(e.Item, GridPagerItem).Paging.DataSourceCount.ToString()
        End If
    End Sub
```